# Are the any examples of set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such as...

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

Are the any examples of set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such as set of limit points of $E$ equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $E$ hasn't any limit points?

I use following difinition of limit point: a limit point of a set $S$ is a point which has points of $S$ other than itself arbitrarily close to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a nonempty set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that either the set of limit points of $E$ is either the integers or empty. There are examples for each.

For $E=\{1\}$ there is no limit point of $E$.

For each integer $n$, define a sequence $(x_{ni})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ as follows. Let $x_{ni}=n-\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}$. Letting $E$ be the union $E=(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z},i\in\mathbb{N}} x_{ni})\cup\mathbb{Z}$, we have that the limit points of $E$ are the integers.